# ImportError while running Google App Engine test project

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am new to Google App Engine and so, I just followed the procedure to test an application which just prints "hello world".

(followed according to Google App Engine Documentation)

The project folder name is "GoogleApp"

This is my Python file:

File Name : sayHello.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def main():
    print "hello"
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This the yaml file

File Name : app.yaml

```
application: GoogleApp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: sayHello.py
```

When ever I just run the project in Google App Engine Launcher, this is the log error I am getting

```
2012-04-19 10:52:23 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--admin_console_server=', '--port=8080', 'D:\\Code\\Projects\\IRCmathBot\\GoogleApp']"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 125, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 121, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py", line 157, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools import appcfg
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 41, in <module>
    import mimetypes
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: Module use of python25.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
2012-04-19 10:52:25 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Actually, I use Python 2.7. The above log says that python25.dll conflicts with version of python.

I don't know what exactly it means but I could interpret that

1. It should either support only python 2.5 or
2. It I should have used python 2.5 code.

as the 2nd isn't possible and Google supports 2.7,  I don't know what is this error.

Try to figure out myself but couldn't succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something's seriously broken with your Python 2.7 installation - parts of it are referencing Python 2.5 libraries. You should uninstall all versions of Python on your machine, and reinstall the version(s) you need.

Comment: It is not a problem in Python 2.7 install - it is a problem with launcher.

Comment: @techtonik The launcher does not (or at least, did not) bundle Python; the issue was with Python itself.

Comment: Launcher won't work without bundled python25.dll, because it uses wxPython bindings compiled against this lib.

Comment: @techtonik That's the case now - but this answer was written over a year ago, before Python was bundled with the launcher.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about that. If you take GoogleAppEngine-1.5.5.msi released two years ago on October 11, 2011, the python25.dll is there.

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar problem (while running the tutorial code), and solved it by checking my PythonPath system environment variable.

For me, OpenCV edited the PythonPath variable to point to its own directory structure instead of the base Python installation itself.

You can edit the environment variables by opening up the 'Advanced System Properties' window and clicking on the 'Environment Variables' button. The 'PythonPath' variable under 'System Variables'. At the minimum, it should include the path of your python executable, such as 'C:\Python27\'.

Comment: I had the same issue with PYTHONPATH. In my situation, there is a link to Mapnik. When I removed the link, Google App Engine works good.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried in command-line? Forget the launcher.
I had same problem! I re-installed Python several times, changed versions. It was hilarious. 
With version 2.5 launcher can start the server, but the application doesn't work, but I can upload it online through launcher.
With Python ver. 2.7, launcher displays same problems you're dealing with. I also can't get the server started locally. But command-line works well, both starting the server locally and uploading online.
So I'll stick with version 2.7. Hope it helps, let me know..

Answer (score 1):

You have threadsafe enabled, so you should use WSGI handlers. That could be the problem. I would replace your code with the following:

File: helloworld.py

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Hello, WebApp World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)])
```

File: app.yaml

```
application: GoogleApp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app
```

If using Python2.7 on Google AppEngine, refer to this official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27) to create your first "Hello World" Application.

Comment: I did try even without threadsafe statement. However, it didn't work!!

Comment: What documentation did you base your code on? If you're using Python2.7, the official documentation for getting started is https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld ...the code you provided doesn't look like you based it from those docs. Maybe you based it on the Python25 docs.

Comment: Could you try out the instructions from the link I gave above instead and see if that works for you? :)

Comment: yeah. please give me a minute

Comment: If it's not your code, then it could be a problem with either your Google App Engine SDK installation or your Python installation or both. I apologize, but I can't think of any suggestions at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this after 3 hrs of effort. Reinstall cannot solve my problem, messing around the user/system environment variable also not work. 
Follow this step work:

Open Google Drive Perference, turn off auto run after win start up
turn off Google Drive
or simply uninstall google drive (Google Drive seems using Python 2.5 _socket library

uninstall python and GAE
reboot
install python27 and GAE
Most importantly, specify a new path, do not use the default c:\python27 again (I changed it to c:\mypython27. same as GAE, use a new path.

Then it works again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've added the GAE path into the environment variable PATH? Just remove it.

I had exactly the same problem with you, it seems to me that Python 2.7 will try to use an incorrect _socket.pyd lib under GAE path, removing GAE path from PATH will fix this.

It needs no extra coding, just a tiny configuration of your win OS. 
Since my OS language is Chinese, names of icons/links below are translated from Chinese by myself, which i cannot guarantee to be correct :(

1. Right click on the "Computer" icon, choose 'Properties', you'll see the system panel showing some basic system information;
2. Click on the "Advanced System Settings" link, you'll see the system property panel containing several tabs;
3. Choose the "Advanced" tab, there should be a button named "Environment variables" on the bottom, click on it then you can see a dialog displaying all environment variables of your system;
4. Find and edit the variable named "PATH" or "Path" (case insensible): if its value contains a path to your GAE, then remove the GAE path.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was that I did set the System Variable PYTHONPATH to '.'. Deleting the variable did the job!

Answer (score 0):

I set PYTHON_PATH to

> "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine;C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\antlr3;**C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_0_96**;C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib;C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\graphy;C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\ipaddr;C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson;C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webob;C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml\lib"

but then I realize that django 0.96 require python 2.5, so use django 1.4, and it works fine.

> "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine;C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\antlr3;**C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.4**;C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib;C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\graphy;C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\ipaddr;C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\simplejson;C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webob;C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml\lib"

If you have same problem as above, just check PATH, PYTHON_PATH to see whether mismatch version between library and python. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Some programs may modify the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. If you check it's value (System -> Environment variables) and ensure it is set to the correct python 2.7 path (default C:\Python27) then this should fix the issue. In my case something had set it to my google appengine path.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImportError: Module use of python25.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

The problem is that `python25.dll` conflicts with your Python 2.7 installation. This `python25.dll` comes from the greatly outdated Google App Engine Launcher for Windows and is located in `C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\launcher`

It is not a problem of your Python 2.7 install - it is a problem of Launcher, who injects its own Python path into app environment. To test that, add the following lines at the top of `google_appengine/dev_appserver.py` after first imports:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(sys.path)
```

Then re-run you app to get fresh log and see for yourself:

```
...
'C:\\OpenCV2.3\\opencv\\build\\python\\2.7',
'C:\\Google\\google_appengine\\launcher',
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
...
```

I got the launcher from Python .msi SDK 1.8.8, and it is of course suxx that Google still ships several versions of SDK with broken GUI tool. To fix that, add the following after first imports in `dev_appserver.py`:

```
# --- Repair sys.path after broken GAE Windows Launcher
# see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222342/
ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
LAUNCHPATH = os.path.join(ROOT, 'launcher')
if LAUNCHPATH in sys.path:
  sys.stderr.write('[BUG] GAE Windows Launcher detected. Fixing..\n')
  sys.path.remove(LAUNCHPATH)
# /--
```

Unfortunately, you'll need to repeat the procedure when new version of GAE comes out. There is an [issue #8568](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8568) on AppEngine tracker that you can star and comment to make it fixed someday.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a PYTHONPATH variable in Environment Variables? delete it and restart the Google App Engine Launcher,it will work!